# python flag based on conditional if logic using three different columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have the following df based on google analytics data:

```
Customer | transaction_id | medium   | first_transaction_flag
ABC        12345            organic      Y
ABC        23456            email        0    
ABC        34567            organic      0
BCD        45678            organic      0
BCD        56789            referral     0
```

In the above df, the transaction 12345 has a first_transaction_flag of Y, which means that this was the customer's first transaction ever.

I need to add a second flag labeled first_channel. What it should do is flag for that one customer that channel, where they were acquired as their first_channel = Y for all subsequent transactions. This would be the output:

```
Customer | transaction_id | medium   | first_transaction_flag | first_channel
ABC        12345            organic      Y                       Y
ABC        23456            email        0                       0
ABC        34567            organic      0                       Y             
BCD        45678            organic      0                       0
BCD        56789            referral     0                       0
```

Basically, it would be a conditional if statement: if first_transaction_flag = Y, then mark the same combo of customer and medium as Y. I was trying to think if it is possible with a loc or np.where statement, but didn't get far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cols = ['Customer', 'medium']
col = 'first_transaction_flag'
df.assign(first_channel=df.groupby(cols)[col].transform('first'))

  Customer  transaction_id    medium first_transaction_flag first_channel
0      ABC           12345   organic                      Y             Y
1      ABC           23456     email                      0             0
2      ABC           34567   organic                      0             Y
3      BCD           45678   organic                      0             0
4      BCD           56789  referral                      0             0
```

---

**Explanation**

`'first'` will grab the first result within a group and `transform` broadcasts it across all indices for that group.

Comment: Thank you so much - do you mind explaining 'first' in the very end of the statement and where you defined that the column first_channel should display a Y for the match?

Comment: I added some explanation

Comment: Great - thank you! I just ran it and it gives me Y/N - this is perfect; thank you very much

Comment: This works if the table is properly sorted, i.e. the `first_transaction_flag` is set to `Y` for the first transaction.  To ensure the desired behavior, you may want to consider pre-sorting via `df.sort_values(['Customer', 'first_transaction_flag'], ascending=[True, False])`

Comment: Thank you @Alexander - I had no idea and my huge df was definitely not sorted that way - you saved me quite a lot of trouble shooting later on, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to solve your problem, but this worksm too:

```
fc = df[df['first_transaction_flag'] == 'Y'][['Customer', 'medium']]
fc['first_channel'] = 'Y'
df = df.merge(fc, how='outer').fillna(0)
```